# Microwave oven: from power to temperature

Tags: power, temperature, heat

You have a microwave oven which lets you set the power, \$P\$, and time, \$\tau\$, during which you will heat something.

You also know that you need to bring an object to a specific temperature, \$T\$, and keep it at that temperature for \$t\$ minutes.

Could you explain how to get a formula and/or a model for such purposes?

Comment: What were your attempts and what did you not understand..? We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: Looking for a formula or something like that, it seemed to me that you need to know something about properties of the material you have to heat. I am not able to find a general formula.

Comment: To "add" temperature you must overcome the loss of heat + add energy to the item. To maintain temperature you just have to add the heat that is lost to "ambient".

Comment: Is it possible to approximate a microwave oven as a system where loss of heat is null and so is the heat lost to ambient?

Comment: You'd have to ask the one who created the exercise, but assuming from the second question, I'd say no. (If no heat is lost then you need 0 energy to maintain temp).

Comment: This would better off in Physics.SE rather than here, as it's a thermodynamics question. The microwave being the heat source does not make it an electronics engineering question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to move it there?

Answer (score 1):

The temperature of an object in a microwave after some arbitrary time will depend on quite a few factors, not all of which are easy to find out.

Aside from input power and time, you also have the power absorbed by the object being heated (just because it's a 700W microwave, doesn't mean 700W is always delivered, much like a 600hp sports car doesn't always use 600hp).

The amount of power absorbed by the object will depend on what it's made of ([dielectric heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating) is the mean mechanism for non-metallic objects and can be quite hard to calculate sometimes... I mean, does anyone know the dielectric constant of a chicken?)

The placement is also important as most microwaves have spots where the microwave energy is more concentrated and spots where it's weaker, so that will have an effect.

The absorption of the microwaves is probably non-linear, so the microwaves might heat the outside more than the inside as the microwaves get adsorbed on their journey to the center... (of the chicken?)

The [specific heat/heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) of the object is important as objects with a higher specific heat value require more energy to be heated by the same amount. E.g. it takes a little over 4 joules (or 4 watt-seconds) to heat 1 gram of water by 1'C, but it only takes 0.13J to heat a gram of tungsten or 14.3J to heat a gram of hydrogen by the same amount. So the material will partially dictate how quickly a fixed power source will heat that object.

It's also important to know the [latent heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat) (melting or boiling energy) as melting and boiling tend to happen at a constant temperature. This is why normal boiling water hits 100'C and *stays there*, it doesn't continue to increase in temperature.

Also important is the rate of heat loss to the environment. This has 3 forms, radiative, conductive and convective. [Radiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation) is IR radiation (it's what snakes and thermal cameras see) and is dependent on the difference in temperature of the object vs everything around it and on how well the object emits IR (black objects emit IR well, shiny things don't). [Conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) is heat lost through touching surfaces and depends on the temperature difference and an object's thermal conductivity. [Convective heat loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) is based on the movement of hot air carrying the heat away and because it involves fluid dynamics it's a lost cause trying to calculate it, which is unfortunate because for anything not very thermally conductive or glowing bright orange, it's usually the main source of heat loss.

There's probably something else I've forgotten, but as you can see, working out how quickly a microwave heats things is by no means a straight forward process. But that doesn't mean you can't draw some conclusions from some empirical tests, go for it, try a few experiments and see what happens. After all, discovery requires experimentation :)